# Read file from txt and split string using comma

Tags: java, split

Why is it it says that there is no split method found ? I want to split one lines to several parts. But there is error. Why is that so ?

```
 try {
        Scanner a = new Scanner (new FileInputStream ("product.txt"));

        while (a.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(a.nextLine()); //this works correctly, all the lines are displayed
            String[] temp = a.split(",");

        }
        a.close();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
```

Comment: Why would you think that there was a `split` method on `Scanner` instances? There's none metioned in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#method_summary).

Answer (score 4):

`split()` is not defined for `Scanner` but for `String`.

Here's a quick fix:

```
        String line = a.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line); //this works correctly, all the lines are displayed
        String[] temp = line.split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

`split` method works on the `String` and not on the `Scanner`. So store the contents of

```
a.nextLine()
```

in a string like this

```
String line = a.nextLine();
```

and then use split method on this stirng

```
String[] temp = line.split(",");
```

Comment: Or `a.nextLine().split(",")`.